# Does "Baldur's Gate 3" run on MacBook Air 2020 M1?

Tags: baldurs-gate-3

I have a

`MacBook Air 2020: Chip M1 (the weakest you),8GB RAM`

can I play Baldur's Gate 3 on it?

Is someone have done it and tell me its experience with it

Thank you

Comment: Well, you can’t for at least another few weeks, as the Mac release has been delayed until September…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a look at the recommended requirements

https://larian.com/support/faqs/system-requirements_47

More importantly the few lines about Mac systems.

> Additional notes on the minimum requirements:
>
> - The game requires a CPU with AVX2 support (basically, 2014 or later).
> - Nvidia graphics are not supported.
> - The minimum AMD graphics card requires 4GB of VRAM; cards with 2GB would require swapping assets in and out of memory, likely causing performance problems, and are not recommended.
> - Since integrated graphics share system memory, having more than 8GB would help when using M1 systems.

So it seems that you will experience a 'low quality' experience, due to a lack of RAM.

Comment: I'll coerce my little brother to make an account on my tiny mac when the ios version releases and try if it explodes, I'll let you know.
Thank you Neon1024 <3

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Neon1024's answer, with [Patch #3](https://baldursgate3.game/news/patch-3-mac-support-magic-mirror-more_93), Baldur's Gate 3 is now fully supported on Mac. This also entails changes in Mac system requirements:

> **Mac Support**
>
> With Patch 3, Baldur’s Gate 3 is now fully supported on Mac!
>
> As with the PC release in August, saves made in previous versions of BG3 on Mac will not be compatible with the full release. To prepare your Mac for the full version of Baldur’s Gate 3 and minimise potential compatibility issues, we recommend you fully uninstall the game and remove any mods before installing the latest version.
>
> The minimum and recommended specs for Mac users have also been updated: we recommend an M1 Pro processor and FSR enabled to run the game at high or ultra settings on a Retina display. Check the [Steam store page](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1086940/Baldurs_Gate_3/) for more details.
>
> Mac players, thank you for your patience – now, gather your party and venture forth.

Comment: technically I can play with minimum settings <3
you made my day Joachim!